# I'm stuck fighting Colter in Nukaworld, how do I beat him?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm stuck on Colter. I have tried everything, but I can't kill him. I have no recent saves, so reloading is not an option. I also have no missiles or a Fat Man, however, I *do* have a shotgun and a spray n pray, but only 56 bullets. I also do not have any power armor around. How can I defeat Colter in my current state?

Comment: The user account was deleted already?  What happened there?  I guess answering this question, or asking for additional information, would be fruitless.

Comment: @can-ned_food - Ah, I don’t believe so. I think this is just a natural consequence of migrating to a site where the user does not have an account. The migration link should lead the user to this site, where they can then create another account.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171196/328832).

Comment: “How can I defeat Colter in my current state?” You just gotta believe in yourself, guy.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to beat him with conventional weapons. You are supposed to use the water gun.

Answer (score 5):

You should have gotten a gun called "thirst zapper". You have to shoot him with it until he is not "electrified" anymore and then you can shoot with your normal weapons.